# add website to google

Tags: web

can someone tell me how can I add a website to google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl

You should probably look into [Google's Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=true&nui=1&continue=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl%3Den&followup=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl%3Den&hl=en) as well.

Comment: I did this, (2 monts ago) and still nothing... how long did it takes to index my page?

Comment: Read up on Google's Webmaster Guidelines: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769. This will explain what to do and what not to do. In addition, Google tends to index sites that gets updated on a regular bases more often than say a standard pamphlet style company website.

Comment: I read this and I think that my page meet all the criteria.I added a sitemap to webmaster... how long it takes that google index my site?

Comment: Straight from Google: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2172a84d24b88442&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.google.co.uk/addurl/?continue=/addurl

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl

Just go to the page and enter the url along with the comments and enter the captcha and your site will be added to the queue of list( Add with the prefix: http:// )